# Find with current location in Maps Activity, my code doesn't work

Tags: android, maps

This is my code:

```
package com.example.claudio.mapsp4;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback {

private LocationManager locationManager;
private android.location.LocationListener locationListener;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private final static int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;
private Button btn;
private TextView txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new android.location.LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                txt.setText("clicked");
                Address l = addresses.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You are here"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET
            }, 10);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        configureButton();
    }
}

private void configureButton() {
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);

        }
    });

}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}


public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResult)
{
   switch(requestCode){
       case 10:
           if(grantResult.length>0 &&  grantResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
               configureButton();
           return;
   }
}

}
```

When I click on the button, it doesn't show my current location, and the `textField` isn't update..

Comment: have you tried debugging to see why this isn't working? Go debug and stop on the lines above the text change, you will see where the problem comes from

Comment: Have you read documentation about receiving location updates? https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html